# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 73776

Tags: python, windows, encoding

This is a Django project.
Encountering error upon running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in a local virtualenv.

```
Collecting https://github.com/jedestep/Zappa/archive/layer-support.zip (from -r requirements\base.txt (line 9))
Using cached https://github.com/jedestep/Zappa/archive/layer-support.zip
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user~1\desktop\project\project\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize
    ; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-6htw2gh2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\
    \Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-6htw2gh2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(
    __file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' e
    gg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-6htw2gh2\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-6htw2gh2\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-6htw2gh2\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        long_description = readme_file.read()
      File "c:\users\user~1\desktop\project\project\venv\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 73776: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

The requirements do install as expected in the vagrant environment, however I recall that it would also work locally on my machine. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what was the change that lead to this error, it may have been the result of a pull.

Versions:
`Python: 3.6.5`
`Django: 2.2`
`pip: 20.0.2`

I have run `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but it does not change the error. 
A similar error will occur with the automatic test database downloads when I try to run `tox`.

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The requirements do install as expected in the vagrant environment, however I recall that it would also work locally on my machine. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what was the change that lead to this error, it may have been the result of a pull.

The issue is with the package you're trying to install, and the configuration of your environment. I guess the package updated at one point and broke because they added emoji to their readme or something: if you look a bit at the error message you can see there's a problem in reading stuff into `long_description`, check [the package's setup.py](https://github.com/jedestep/Zappa/blob/master/setup.py) and you can find the issue near the start:

```py
with open('README.md') as readme_file:
    long_description = readme_file.read()
```

The problem here is that when you `open` a file without specifying a mode it's going to be "text" so python will automatically decode bytes to str, which is cool, except the *encoding* it uses for such decoding is the "default" one for the system (found by calling `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`), which often is not what's desirable.

Your Vagrant environment and the developer's machine probably have a UTF8 default encoding (as most unix systems would these days), meanwhile your local windows box does not and uses CP1252 by default which blows up. Sadly I'm not much of a windows user (for dev) so I've no idea how to change the "default encoding", that may even not be possible given what a cursory search of SO yields.

I would suggest:

- asking the package author to fix their setup.py to explicitly specify an `encoding` when opening file
- trying to find out more about `getpreferredencoding`'s internal decisions, and whether it's possible to override the preferredencoding via the environment in Windows (it's apparently possible / easy to override the encoding for the standard stream but `chcp` / [`set PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) apparently don't do anything for a normal `open`)
- running your thing on the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which would probably work out of the box

PS: I've taken the liberty of updating your post's tags as django, pip and eggs really have nothing to do with the actual issue

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will explore your suggestions and if they yield something add the details in a comment.

Comment: As a side-note if I open the shell and run `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` it returns `'utf-8'`, but I think that's what it should return right?

Comment: `open` calls `getpreferredencoding(False)` not `getfilesystemencoding()`. "filesystem encoding" is a completely unrelated function used to transcode file *names*.